# Ubuntu support for motherboard that supports other Linux distros

Tags: asus, gpu, distro-recommendation, motherboard

I want to buy a motherboard that supports Linux, specifically Ubuntu 16.04 or above as I want mainly to use Tensorflow and [Ubuntu is the only distro that is officially supported](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux).

I have looked at a [list the manufacturer provides](https://dlcdnimgs.asus.com/websites/global/aboutASUS/OS/Linux170105.pdf) and the one I have been suggested Strix X99 appears as supporting Fedora and Red Hat. For Ubuntu it says N/A.

What are the chances Ubuntu is supported? Does anyone has that motherboard? any other suggestions for a high end motherboard that can host 128 Gb of RAM and 1 ( or 2 ) GPU?

Comment: No specific advice, but generally hardware support is done in the kernel. Except for some minor version differences and distro-specific alterations, the kernels of most distros are quite similar. If you use 16.04.3 or so, which comes with kernel 4.10 already, I would expect you to be fine.

Comment: If you search for "ubuntu asus Strix X99", there are lots of hits. You really should do a minimal amount of homework.

Comment: This is not an opinion based question and not a hardware specific one. It is a good question to ask if hardware supported by one Linux distro will be supported by Ubuntu.

Comment: @mikewhatever , you are right that I could have googled the answer but beyond knowing what I am asking I also wanted to understand why. Sorry I didn't make my question more explicit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All hardware specific features are in the Linux kernel. If the motherboard claims to be compatible with some Linux distro, then it means that the vanilla Linux kernel (in 99% of cases), or some distro specific patсhes or kernel packages support this hardware.

This means that most likely the motherboard will work with any Linux distro. In rare cases that distro maintainers added some patches to support something, it can be easily enough be done with another distro.

Open source software is good because if someone managed to write a driver for same specific software, it can be "stolen" and used in any other distro. The best case is when the solution is applied to the upstream kernel source, then it almost automatically gets sooner or later to all distributions with kernel upgrades.

A bad case is when some hardware is not supported anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Why would someone add specific hardware support in a distro and not to the kernel? Doesn't  seem efficient nor very open source way of doing things?

Comment: There may be some reasons, e.g. upstream maintainers reject a patch.